# 3 columns in the GRID system

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

I need to leave these 3 images and texts in 3 columns, aligned, how to do?

`<section class="py-5 grey lighten-4" id="team">`
 `<div class="container">`
   `<div class="wow fadeIn">`
   `<h1 class="h1 pt-5 pb-3 text-center">Equipe  <strong>NOLS</strong></h1>`
  `<p class="px-5 mb-5 pb-3 lead text-center blue-grey-text">`
        ONE TWO
  `</p>`
 `</div>`

-------------FROM HERE---------------------

`<div class="row mb-lg-4 center-on-small-only">`
  `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-r wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s">`
   `<div class="col-md-6 float-left"><img class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1 mb-3"' src="img/erick.jfif" alt="team member"/></div>`
      `<div class="col-md-6 float-right">`
       `<div class="h4">Erick Henrique</div>`
       `<h5 class="font-bold blue-grey-text mb-4">Diretor de sistemas</h5>`
       `<a href="" target="_blank"><i`class="fa fa-linkedin"> ONE  
  
   `</div>`
 
      `<div class="col-md-6 float-left"><img class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1 mb-3"`src="img/joao.jfif" alt="team member"/>
      `<div class="col-md-6 float-right">`
 João Vitor Valentim
        `<h5 class="font-bold blue-grey-text mb-4">Diretor WEB</h5>`
        O responsável por toda parte do desenvolvimento WEB da **NOLS.**

João Vitor Valentim
     `</div>`
  
  `</div>`
 
    `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-r wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s">`
   src="img/nicolas.jfif" alt="team member"/></div>
  
        `<div class="h4">Nicolas Bartoli</div>`
  Diretor de criação
       `<h5>  <p class="grey-text"  style="text-align: justify;">    O responsável por toda parte de`design, publicidade e propaganda da **NOLS.**   href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i><span class="ml-1">Nicolas Bartoli</span></a>
  
    `</div>` 

`

Comment: you should format the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column widths should add up to 12 on each row. Right now, I only see ONE column of 6 on line 2. Everything else is inside that column due to lack of closing tags. You're also mixing H4 tags with  which are an unnecessary use of DIV that only added to your confusion. It's obvious that what you copied is probably not your real code, as there are a lot of missing bits.

```
<div class="row mb-lg-4 center-on-small-only"> 
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-r wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s"> 
    <div class="col-md-6 float-left"></div> 
    <div class="col-md-6 float-right"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 float-left">
      <div class="col-md-6 float-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-r wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s"></div> 
  </div>
```

After I've cleaned up your code segment and eliminated all the non-grid related items, you are missing one close-DIV tag at the bottom. Furthermore, it's obvious you only have ONE column of 6 inside the row tag, due to bad or missing close-DIV tags.

You really should start using more row tags, as the way you are organizing them is just frankly, unreadable and horrible. No wonder you don't know which tag to close where.